# Symfony2 Error 500 - Class does not exist on Dev Server - Works fine on production server

Tags: php, symfony

I've been fighting a losing battle against issues with Symfony recently, and today it has decided not to work on my local development server at all.

**Error message:**

> Class AppBundle\Controller\routeCleaner does not exist in /var/www/html/src/AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "/var/www/html/app/config/routing.yml").

The file exists in the directory and is `chmod 777` as a last resort to no avail.

On the production server I have no error being thrown and it works fine, the exact same configuration on both machines; or at least should be unless something has gone wrong.

Comment: Well we don't something like this every day :) Usually, it is a production which makes all kinds of issues ;)

Comment: Does the error occur when running via `app_dev.php` only or always on you dev server? Might be worth checking `routing_dev.yml` to see if you made some c/p error...

Comment: Seems to happen for both app.php and app_dev.php - everything inside routing_dev.yml looks good. I'm very confused as this has never happened before.

Comment: can you grep your entire project for keyword `routeCleaner`? Ultimately, if you made some unaware changes to `vendor` (which I assume is not under `VCS`), you might just delete everything there and run `composer install` to rebuild

Comment: @NikhilVaghela: feedback on your edit. You don't need to backtick proper nouns like "Symfony" since it is not code. Names of technologies can just be written with an initial cap or all-caps for acronyms, and do not need any other formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes ran into those kind of problems if the production or the development environment weren´t both case sensitive / case insensitive. 
Can you double check that?